# When Background Service and Activity runs simultaneously, memory usage gets bigger

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

I have a receiver. This receiver on receive of BOOT_COMPLETED or START_BACKGROUND_SERVICE (Custom) starts a background service. After starting service, If don't launch application my background service memory usage is at most 25MB. If I launch the app, usa of memory goes infinitely higher.

If I don't start background service and start just the activity memory usage is just like 20Mb. When both runs, something goes wrong.

What can be the problem?

This is background service;

```
public class OnClearFromRecentService extends Service {

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.d("ClearFromRecentService", "Service Started");
    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d("ClearFromRecentService", "Service Destroyed");
}

@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
    Log.e("ClearFromRecentService", "END");
    //Code here
    stopSelf();
}}
```

This code is in Receiver

```
public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
Intent backgroundService;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (backgroundService == null){
        backgroundService = new Intent(context, OnClearFromRecentService.class);
    }

    if (intent.getAction().equals("START_BACKGROUND_SERVICE")){
        context.startService(backgroundService);
        Log.i("TTW","STARTED");
    }else if(intent.getAction().equals("STOP_BACKGROUND_SERVICE")){
        context.stopService(backgroundService);
        Log.i("TTW","STOPPED");
    }else if(intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")){
        context.startService(backgroundService);
        Log.i("TTW","STARTED");
    }else Log.i("TTW","NOTHING HAPPEN");

}}
```

What can be the problem? Please help me.

Comment: Memory management is depends on android OS, It's not in our hand to manage it.

Comment: Yes it is. But memory usage goes to 1GB then it close it self. Because of out of memory. So there must be something wrong

Comment: I don't think so background service consume more than 1GB of memory.. What you have in background Service?

Comment: Ibeacon Scanning with BLE

Comment: Also in the activity I have only **webview**. If the activity on foreground memory usage goes up if. If stopped it just wait. After activity gets foreground it continues to growing up.